# TypeScript requirejs issue with loading external modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I am having issues with this game.js code that the game.ts file compiles to:

```
var GameObjects = require("./GameObjects")
```

I have set up my page index.html js imports as so:

```
<script language="javascript" src="javascripts/require.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script language="javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script language="javascript" src="ts/GameObjects.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script language="javascript" src="ts/game.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

and this is the error in chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined GameObjects.js:82
Uncaught Error: Module name "GameObjects" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

any ideas friends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where the idea of hand-editing the JavaScript files has come from. If you compile your TypeScript with the `--module amd` flag, you shouldn't need to edit the JavaScript files as the `import` statements will be converted into `require` statements.

The only script tag you should need on your page is this:

```
<script src="javascripts/require.js" data-main="ts/game.js"></script>
```

Once require.js has loaded, it will then load game.js, and whenever it comes across a `require` statement (which is your `import` statement in your TypeScript file) it will then load that script and then execute the code.

You can load in jQuery and GameObjects and any other modules just by adding `import` statements in your TypeScript file.

Comment: thx +1,  If my solution only has 1 project what is the best way to reloud it, I don't see the option in the project menu :(

Comment: so like this:     <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc --module amd&quot; -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>

Comment: Yes - although the `--target ES5` belongs before the `&quot;` (if you really want to target ES5).

Comment: hmm now VS builds with success but the new JS files are not updated, I reverted out the new argument and still the same issue. VS 2012 really needs to improve the typescript stuff

Comment: fixed it with this:   <Exec   Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; -module amd -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />

Answer (score 3):

You have no `data-main` attribute in your require.js `script` tag. Please read [the RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) carefully.

In a nuthshell: you should be loading `ts/GameObjects.js` from a top-level `require` call, which you put in the file specified in the `data-main` attribute. e.g. (from the docs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             javascripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
        <script data-main="javascripts/main" src="javascripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in `javascripts/main.js` (you can actually call it whatever you want, as long as it matches what you put in `data-main`), you call `require` and load your modules and do whatever you want with them:

```
require(["ts/GameObjects.js", "ts/game.js"], function(GameObjects, Game) {
  ... use 'GameObjects' and 'Game' here ...
});
```

Remember that in `ts/GameObjects.js` and `ts/game.js` you need to wrap your code in `define()` calls, so they are interpreted as modules.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, but is there any way I can get by without manually editing the js files as they are generated by the typescript compiler?

Comment: You mean "ts/GameObjects.js" and "ts/game.js"? If so then no, there isn't, you absolutely need the `define` calls in there.

Comment: so every time I compile my ts file I have to manually edit the js files? if so I won't bother with external modules :( How would I modify the below outputed .js file?

Comment: (function (GameObjects) {
    var Player = (function () {
        function Player() {
            this.color = "#00A";
            this.x = 50;
            this.y = 270;
            this.width = 20;
            this.height = 30;
        }

Comment: Why don't you just read the [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)? That's what it's there for. Anyway the function you posted has syntax errors, there are not enough closing brackets.